# Batch conversion of matrices into data frames in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a bunch of R matrices that need to converted to data frames, I hope I can automate this process.

```
    x = matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10)
    y = matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10)
    z = matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10)
    x = as.data.frame(x)
    y = as.data.frame(y)
    z = as.data.frame(z)
```

This will not work:

```
    lapply(c('x', 'y', 'z'), function(i) assign(i, as.data.frame(get(i))))
```

Comment: *Why* do you need to convert them in the first place? Many operations are faster on matrices than they are on data frames.

Comment: Is there a reason you did not put all the matrices in a list to begin with?

Comment: @AnandaMahto I need to use mapply on these data frames. It seems to me matrices will not do.

Comment: @CravingSpirit this is a misuse of `lapply`. The `*apply` family are not intended for situations where you want to change the state of variables in your environment. Stick to a for loop for these sorts of things, `for (name in c('x', 'y', 'x')) {....}`.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde Thanks, I will do just that. But this also turns out to be a good opportunity to get to know R environments better.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `lapply()`. You're not intending to return a list.

```
for (i in c('x', 'y', 'z')) assign(i, as.data.frame(get(i)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the help file for `?assign`, you'll find the following as the usage:

```
assign(x, value, pos = -1, envir = as.environment(pos),
       inherits = FALSE, immediate = TRUE)
```

If you really want to do this, add `envir = .GlobalEnv` to your `assign` statement, and the objects will be overwritten.

Comment: -1 here means shift the frame one level higher, i.e. the parent frame?

Comment: What should I do if x, y and z are not in the GlobalEnv but in the, say, grandparent environment?

Comment: @CravingSpirit, you specify the environment to get them from with the `envir` argument from `get`. I usually find it easier to specify where to look or assign using `envir` instead of `pos`.

Comment: @CravingSpirit, `example(get)` and `example(assign)`. Sorry. Not sure what you're looking for in a code chunk. `lapply(c('x', 'y', 'z'), function(i) assign(i, as.data.frame(get(i)), envir = .GlobalEnv))`?

Comment: I mean the envir=some_specific_envir part, i.e. what is the format for specifying it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can perfectly well use `mapply` on matrices. A matrix is a vector with dimension attributes so run `mapply` on the matrices (which will give you a results as long as the product of the number of rows and columns) and dimension the result back to the correct size matrix afterwards:

```
x = matrix(rnorm(16), 4)
y = matrix(rnorm(16), 4)
z = matrix(rnorm(16), 4)

matrix( mapply( sum , x , y , z ) , ncol = ncol(x) )
#          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
#[1,] -0.2707872 -1.3272743  0.4656883  0.1357950
#[2,]  0.7026622 -0.7754597 -1.1339546 -1.2705671
#[3,]  1.2174994  0.2062436 -0.8471821 -1.5186123
#[4,]  3.3559925  1.7008927  1.7765929  0.4737344
```

And, as has been pointed out, much faster than using data.frames. What is the function you are intending to use with `mapply`? Is there some reason this will not work, but will work with data.frames?

Comment: But what if I want to do something like this? `mapply(cor, x, y)` for the correlation of corresponding columns.

Comment: @CravingSpirit my first instinct would be to use `sapply` for that `t( sapply( 1:ncol(x) , function(i) cor( x[,i] , y[,i] ) ) )` but you do have to assume that `x` and `y` are in the global environment.

Comment: @CravingSpirit and if you had to specify the environment to look for these matrices in you could do `t( sapply( 1:ncol(x) , function(i) cor( get("x" , env = grandparent)[,i] , get("y" , env = grandparent)[,i] ) ) )` (not sure if that's a good idea or not - can't decide)